# Vue components are not rendered

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use Vue components in static HTML pages. Vue components are not rendered and when I do "Vue" in the browser console, it says Vue is undefined. A comment is inserted in the #app element like: `<!--function(e,n,r,o){return Be(t,e,n,r,o,!0)}-->`.

What I am trying to do is the following:

- Make an app mainly with static HTML and use Vue components (Single File Components) to enhance UX on some pages (not SPA, and I have no plan to use Vue Router for now)
- I do not want to use an App.vue in which I would have to define the components used along with a Vue instantiation and a render function (i.e. `new Vue({ render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')`); instead, I want to freely use Vue components (Single File Components) anywhere within the #app element in different static HTML pages.
- Use Webpack and vue-loader
- Make a build/chunk per html page that includes only the specific code for components used; commonly used components and vendor code (i.e. Vue) in other chunk(s).
- Make the builds as small as possible

Below are simplified code samples of my project.

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    page1: './src/page1_main.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ],
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'css/[name].css', chunkFilename: 'css/[name].css' }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  
   optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
         cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
               test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
               name: 'vendor',
               chunks: 'all'
            }
         }
      },
      runtimeChunk: { name: 'manifest' }
   }
};
```

**page1_main.js**

When instantiating Vue, I pass the #app element, and I expect Vue to render the components inside the #app element in the HTML page.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component1 from './components/Component1.vue';

Vue.component('component1', Component1);

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

**Component1.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="component1">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Component1 message',
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.component1 {
    color: #cc0000;
}
</style>
```

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page 1</title>

        <script defer="defer" src="dist/js/manifest.js"></script>
        <script defer="defer" src="dist/js/vendor.js"></script>
        <script defer="defer" src="dist/js/page1.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/page1.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div>
                Some content here
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    Some content here
                </div>
                <div>
                    <component1></component1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

In page1_main.js, `import Vue from 'vue'` doesn't include the compiler. If I use `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'`, it includes the compiler and it works (components are rendered). What confuses me is that I shouldn't have to include the compiler since I have Single File Components and use vue-loader.

According to [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only):

> When using vue-loader or vueify, templates inside *.vue files are
> pre-compiled into JavaScript at build time. You don’t really need the
> compiler in the final bundle, and can therefore use the runtime-only
> build.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have not included the `page1_main.js` in `page1.html`

Comment: @YashMaheshwari It is included: dist/js/page1.js.

Comment: Oh, I see. Use something like mount to insert the app. `new Vue({ render: h => h(component1) }).$mount('#app')` in page1_main,js

Comment: @YashMaheshwari It does work, but what if I have many components? My code sample above is simplified and I have more than 1 components on every page. I would have to create an App.vue and use `new Vue({ render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')` but that's not what I want. I want to freely use components within the #app element on static HTML pages and I don't want to be restricted to the template in App.vue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to register your component to your vue instance?

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Component1
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that. It didn't fix the problem. I believe this is local component registration vs global in my code sample.

Comment: Can this work?

`import Vue from 'vue';
import Component1 from './components/Component1.vue';

module.exports = {
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
};`

Look at this example: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wus7v)

Comment: Yes the example from the link does work, but it relies on an App.vue that is rendered in the Vue instantiation. I do not want to have an App.vue. When instantiating Vue, I want to pass the #app element, and I want Vue to render what's inside the #app element in the HTML page.